# range of convergence of taylor approximation for $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

My question concerns the function $f = \frac{1}{1-x}$

The derivatives 1,2 ..(n+1) I believe are:

- $f^{(1)} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$
- $f^{(2)} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$
- $f^{(n+1)} = \frac{(n+1)!}{(1-x)^{n+2}}$

The taylor polynomial around $x=0$ would then be

$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k+ R_n(f,0)$

with the lagrange closing term $R_n(f,0)= \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$ and $c$ between $0$ and $x$

I hope so much is correct. Now a simple look at $\lim_{n\to \infty} x^n$ confirms the idea that the terms will go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ if and only if $|x|\lt 1$ but somehow when I try to proof that using $\lim_{n\to \infty} |R_n|$ I get the opposite!

$|R_n(f,0)|= \lvert \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1} \rvert = \lvert \frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{(1-c)^{n+2}}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\rvert = \lvert \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-c)^{n+2}}\rvert$

Taking the limit here:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert \frac{x^{n+1}}{(1-c)^{n+2}}\rvert = L$

Now this limit diverges for values of $|x|<1$

... I've been staring at it but did not find the mistake. Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Why does the limit of $\left | \frac {x^{n+1}} {(1-c)^{n+2}} \right |$ diverge as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $|x| < 1$?

Comment: Hint $:$ $R_n (f,0) = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} x^k = \frac {x^{n+1}} {1-x} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Yes, but can we derive that last line from the first ? Or is that not possible and exactly what the answer by jmerry then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here. The error estimate in Taylor's theorem tells us that the series $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ converges to $\frac1{1-x}$ for $|x|<\frac12$. This is true. The fact that the series also converges to that value for $\frac12\le |x|<1$ (because, you know, it's a geometric series that we can calculate the partial sums of exactly) is irrelevant.

The error estimate in Taylor's theorem is not always sharp; the derivative that goes into it can vary greatly, especially in larger intervals. It is normal for the error estimate from the theorem to lead us to an interval of convergence that isn't the largest possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very well know function that is used A LOT!

Some hints to get you going

(1) Find the general form for $f^n(x)$ at $x = 0$ to form your Maclaurin Series.

(2) Apply the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) to find the region of convergence for $x$.

Btw, you are definitely on the right track!

Comment: Thx! Yes I confirmed with the ratio test that in fact the convergence is as stated in the book. I just did not manage to get the same result with the lagrange term